# What is the actual need for making the model in angular?

Tags: angular, model

Though I am new to angular and not well known about all the concepts of angular. So I just want to know the actual use of the model in observables.

Though, this code:

```
getRestaurants = (): Observable<Restaurant[]> => {
    const restaurants: Restaurant[] = [{
        'RestaurantID': 1,
        'RestaurantName': 'The Restaurant'
    }];
    return restaurants;
};
```

Can be replaced with the following code:

```
getRestaurants = (): Observable<any> => {
    const restaurants: any = [{
        'RestaurantID': 1,
        'RestaurantName': 'The Restaurant'
    }];
    return restaurants;
};
```

My confusion is about why we need to use the model, if it should be, we will need to make the models for all the things that we need to get from API even when the API has a lot of methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a model, but rather a variable type and it is not a part of angular, but a part of typescript, which angular commonly uses. :)

Using `Restaurant[]` instead of `any` allows you to benefit from completion, which typescript introduces (for example, if you use a typescript-enabled ide, youll have properties completion for the variable).

If you want to learn about more of the typescript features, check out the official docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Comment: Not necessarly, youll need a type declaration, for complex objects, if you don't have one already (for example shipped in libraries), but there are also built in simple primitives, like boolean, string, number, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When building a big application, this models will help you to write code with fewer bugs and will provide you with very strong autocomplete all around the place. The typings are also very useful in a way that other developers working on the same project will understand easier the logic behind your code (or at least will it figure out faster).

Example:
Imagine that you are dealing with some kind of app for pets (dogs and cats) catalogs, dogs and cats are similar (4 legs 2 eyes and so on), but are different species. In this case, you need class `Pet` and two subclasses `Dog` and `Cat`.
In the begging this knowledge is useless, but as the time passes and the code base grows (and the number of different types of pets), at some point the chance to create some animal instead of other will start growing exponentially. So by using typescript you kind of decrease the chance to do something that you don't want to do.
My self as pure js person, was just like you in the beginning, because all these types in most cases looked like overkill and needles spend time, but as the code base is growing I'm glad that I have TS on my side :D

And as said from the answers above, typings are sugar from TS, not a mandatory angular rule.